# Finding when a UDP packet is actually transmitted on OpenWrt router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt, wifi-transfer

I'm using a Linksys WRT 1900 ACS router with OpenWrt 15.05.1. I'm running a C program on it that sends certain WiFi UDP Multicast packets at regular intervals (of 16 ms) and then prints the system time on stdout. I can clearly see irregularities at the receiving end, but they don't show up in the printed time values.

This leads me to believe that some level of buffering/waiting is happening even after the sendto() system call returns. How can I get the time at which the packet is actually emitted?

Note: The irregularities are the same across all the receivers on that multicast net, so the problem is not at the receiver end.

Comment: Broadcast/multicast on WiFi is special in regards to encryption and priority. Whatever you’re doing is probably not optimal considering WiFi.

Comment: I believe UDP is designed as a protocol where this wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.

**TL;DR**

The `sendto` function returns as soon as the packet has been sent to the IP stack. The kernel IP stack will process it and will try to send the packet through your WiFi interface.

Here lies the problem, WiFi transmit delay is long (compared to wired Ethernet) and irregular. Here is an example of what latency you should expect :

[image: Wifi VS Wired ping time log]

This logarithmic graph shows ping time delay between my server and my router and between my server and a wireless client. Since `ping` is bidirectional, the unidirectional latency is probably around half of that.

The wired communication shows a ping time around 300us, while the wireless links shows an average 7ms (23 time more delay).

Now almost the same graph, this time linear to highlight irregularity:

[image: Wifi VS Wired ping time linear]

Wifi ping time varies between 6 and 45 ms.

**Solutions ?**

Since the `sendto` function returns sooner than you expect, you can't really measure at which time the packets are sent. If you are really interested at the time at which the packet is sent, you can probably estimate it by waiting a response from the client and halving the back and forth time.

But, **as you already figured out**, all the WiFi clients receive the packet at the same time, since it is a multicast.

So the real question here is : **What are you trying to achieve?**

For instance, if you want all your clients to play the same audio stream at the same time, some kind of software [PLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) should do the trick.

If you want to minimize delay, WiFi you can still try to fine-tune your WiFi settings, particularly those around power saving, on the router and on the clients.

And if you want to achieve some [hard real-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) performance, you should probably just forget WiFi.